# Equivalent of cov_x from (legacy) scipy.optimize.leastsq in scipy.optimize.least_squares

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares

The legacy [scipy.optimize.leastsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq) function returns a `cov_x` parameter:

> cov_x: ndarray
>
> Uses the fjac and ipvt optional outputs to construct an estimate of the jacobian around the solution. None if a singular matrix encountered (indicates very flat curvature in some direction). This matrix must be multiplied by the residual variance to get the covariance of the parameter estimates – see curve_fit.

useful to estimate the variance of the parameter estimates.

What is the equivalent of this parameter in the new [scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html)? There is:

> jac : ndarray, sparse matrix or LinearOperator, shape (m, n)
>
> Modified Jacobian matrix at the solution, in the sense that J^T J is a Gauss-Newton approximation of the Hessian of the cost function. The type is the same as the one used by the algorithm.

but it is not really equivalent.

Comment: You did not explain why you used ```least_squares``` when you want some functionality from ```leastsq```. Maybe you need bounds now, but we don't know. As the docs say, that ```jac``` is depending on the algorithm, ```method='lm'``` (not default!) probably returns the output you would expect. But in this case you will lose some functionality of course.

Comment: I'm actually using both, but since `leastsq` is legacy (see [See also](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) section) I assumed its features would be transported to the "new" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is an obvious equivalent.  `jac` is not the same.  It is an estimate of the Jacobian, a matrix of derivatives used to compute the gradients that optimize the minimum result.

You can perform least squares regression with [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), which will return a covariance matrix.

> Returns:
>
> `popt` : array 
>   Optimal values for the parameters so that the
>   sum of the squared residuals of `f(xdata, *popt) - ydata` is minimized
>
> `pcov` : 2d array 
>   The estimated covariance of `popt`. The diagonals
>   provide the variance of the parameter estimate. To compute one
>   standard deviation errors on the parameters use `perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`. How the sigma parameter affects the estimated
>   covariance depends on absolute_sigma argument, as described above. If
>   the Jacobian matrix at the solution doesn’t have a full rank, then
>   ‘lm’ method returns a matrix filled with np.inf, on the other hand
>   ‘trf’ and ‘dogbox’ methods use Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse to compute
>   the covariance matrix.

See also [`scipy.stats.lingress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html#scipy-stats-linregress), which also does least square and returns a correlation coefficient related to the covariance.

Comment: Thanks pylang. I'm aware about `curve_fit`, I just wanted to confirm there's no direct way to obtain `cov_x` with `least_squares`.